# How to correctly use ngFor in Angular2 web application?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I have a list of messages that I need to show in the table.

The thing is that I need a bit advanced table. It should have hidden row that shows when row is clicked. For that I am using bootstrap *Collapse* for angular2 from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home .

The problem is that I can't make my wanted table because of the lack of knowledge in HTML.

This code snippet loops list and creates rows:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let message of messages | paginate: config">
    <tr>
        <td [class.unseen]="!message.seen" [class.seen]="message.seen">{{message.title}}</td>
        <td [class.unseen]="!message.seen" [class.seen]="message.seen">{{message.created | date:'longDate'}}</td>
        <td class="details-button" (click)="message.collapsed = !message.collapsed; makeMessageSeen(message);" [attr.aria-expanded]="!message.collapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{message.collapsed ? 'More' : 'Less'}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="message.collapsed">
        <td>{{message.text}}</td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now the code creates as many tbody elements as there are messages:

```
<tbody>
    <tr> --title1
    <tr> --hidden1
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr> --title2
    <tr> --hidden2
</tbody> .....
```

Is there a way to create only one tbody element with many tr elements inside so it would look like this...???

```
<tbody>
    <tr> --title1
    <tr> --hidden1
    <tr> --title2
    <tr> --hidden2
    <tr> --title3
    <tr> --hidden3
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can put the `ngFor` on the `tr` element. You'll only get one `tbody` containing multiple `tr` elements that way. Something like this: `<tr *ngFor="let message of messages">`

Comment: @KajNelissen in that way `{{message.text}}` will not be accessible in the second `<tr>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<ng-container>` to wrap your rows and use the `*ngFor` in that container instead of `<tbody>`. Change your html to the following:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages | paginate: config">
        <tr>
            <td [class.unseen]="!message.seen" [class.seen]="message.seen">{{message.title}}</td>
            <td [class.unseen]="!message.seen" [class.seen]="message.seen">{{message.created | date:'longDate'}}</td>
            <td class="details-button" (click)="message.collapsed = !message.collapsed; makeMessageSeen(message);" [attr.aria-expanded]="!message.collapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{message.collapsed ? 'More' : 'Less'}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="message.collapsed">
            <td>{{message.text}}</td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

See this [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvHst5LMF2Iet3nCNBp0?p=preview).